# datagrip introspections (Oracle and PostgreSQL)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, datagrip

I've trying to use 0xDBE as a replace for pgAdmin+PL/SQL Developer + Aginity Workbench for Greenplum, but there is one bad thing in introspection:

The IDE shows wrong DDL both for Oracle and PostgreSQL (and Greenplum also).

---

e.g. it shows this:

```
create VIEW LATENCIES (
    TASK_NAME VARCHAR2(250),
    DESTINATION_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
    APPLIED DATE
);
```

instead of this:

```
create or replace view latencies_new as
select table_schema, destination_name, min(applied) as applied from (
select table_schema, table_name, destination_name, max(unload_start) as applied
  from o2g_applies_full
 where apply_id is not null
   and unload_start > sysdate - 1
 group by table_schema, table_name, destination_name
) group by table_schema, destination_name;
```

in Oracle RDBMS. View and underlying tables are in the same schema, which is chosen for sync in DB options in DataGrip.
Therefore Visualisation diagrams don't work at all.

---

The same situation with Postgres/GP - it can't show real DDL for external tables/views etc.

Is there any way to fix it? Maybe I should change drivers (now I use drivers downloaded from JetBrains site)?

Answer (score 1):

One can try to use `SQL Scripts` → `SQL Generator` action to get DDL:

[image: SQL Generator for View]

[image: SQL Generator for Foreign table]

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself...

If you try to directly copy DDL from Database window (on the left) - you can only copy first code mentioned in original post, but when you choose "View Editor" - "DDL" tab - then you will see full DDL.

Comment: But if still doesn't work with PostgreSQL external tables properly(